# navigationcontroller back button action

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

I'm new on iphone and now I'm trying to implement just a back button action, but I receive the signal `SIGABRT` with message : `back2FirstView not found(return type defaults to id).`
In header file I have : `- (void) back2FirstView;` and the implementation in .m is :

```
- (void)back2FirstView
{
    [navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and the action for back button :

```
-(IBAction)RetourButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"BTN Retour");
    [boiteAOutilsViewController back2FirstView];
}
```

Where is the problem? Please help...

Comment: Show us where you are defining the action on the Back button Item

Comment: How you declared boiteAOutilsViewController? Is it an instance name or Class name?

Comment: is an instance of BoiteAOutilsViewController, where I have implemented the method back2FirstView

Comment: So you have 2 view controllers , one where you are implement back2FirstView and 1 where you call the IBAction?

Comment: Yes...from the second view controller I want to go back to first view controller

Comment: Couldn't a simple [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES] when you call the buttonPressed action be a better solution?

Comment: I tried this too, but it the seem thing...:((

Comment: Hmm could you maybe post a bit more of your code? Some content from first and second view controllers h and m files to clearly see what is where?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3245/discussion-between-ern-simonyi-and-gabrielle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a chat with Gabrielle and the problem was solved by commenting out the back2FirstView call and using `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` in the

> -(IBAction)RetourButtonPressed:(id)sender

action.